# How to send hashmap as JsonObject to a webservice in Java

Tags: java, api, post, apache-httpclient-4.x, org.json

I am trying to make a POST request with a hashmap. The accepted format by the webservice is given below.

```
{ 
"students": [
         {
            "firstName": "Abc",
            "lastName": "XYZ",
            "courses": [
            "Math",
            "English"
            ]
          }
}
```

This is my code

```
HttpClient client2 = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
HttpRequest request2 = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
          .uri(URI.create(POST_URI))
          .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
          .POST(new JSONObject(myMap))
          .build();
```

However, this doesn't work. All the examples I have seen so far only accept string as POST parameter and not map.

Comment: Need u transform myMap in Json? Just use lib Gson,

Comment: I am not familiar with gson. I tried using org.json but I am not successful. Can you let me know how to do it using org.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it seems that you are using the java http client introduced in Java 11. This client required a BodyPublisher to send POST requests.

The `java.net.http.BodyPublishers` class provide you a method named `#ofString(String body)` that you can use to send body.

So you can just build your HttpRequest like that :

```java
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create(POST_URI))
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(yourBody))
    .build();
```

In this case you need to pass a string to the `ofString` method, so you can use a library like Jackson or Gson. I don't know how to do this using Gson but using Jackson it is very simple :

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String yourBody = mapper.writeValueAsString(yourMap);

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create(POST_URI))
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(yourBody))
    .build();
```

That's all :)

EDIT: After a second reading, I would like to point out that you cannot send java objects as is in an http request. You already need to transform your objects in a readable format for the server like json or XML. Java objects are part of the programs we write, the Http protocol is not able to pass these objects as is. That's why we use an intermediate format, thus the server is able to read this format and transform it back into an object